# Upgrading from Django 1.2 to 1.4 - Stricter forms validation?

Tags: django, forms, validation, upgrade

We are currently trying to upgrade from Django 1.2 to 1.4, but we are running into a large number of "Caught FieldError" messages complaining about missing fields in forms, almost as if Django has decided to become much stricter about validating forms with the upgrade.

there is a new block of field validation code that was added in 1.3 that appears to be causing the errors, if the block is taken out, everything works perfectly normally. Are there any severe ramifications to removing this extra validation?

The code we removed is:

```
opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback)
    # make sure opts.fields doesn't specify an invalid field
    none_model_fields = [k for k, v in fields.iteritems() if not v]
    missing_fields = set(none_model_fields) - \
                         set(declared_fields.keys())
    if missing_fields:
        message = 'Unknown field(s) (%s) specified for %s'
        message = message % (', '.join(missing_fields),
                             opts.model.__name__)
        raise FieldError(message)
```

this is from django/forms/models.py around line 207

Apparently the error is Unknown field, not caught FieldError, my apologies.

Comment: There's no message "Caught FieldError" in Django, so this is something from your own code. Please post the code and the error.

Comment: I would avoid changing the Django source code where possible. Fix your forms, rather than deleting chunks of code and hoping it doesn't have any severe ramifications.